# Extjs 6.0 Floating panel in bottom right of viewport

Tags: extjs, panel

Hi I need to place a floating panel exactly at the bottom right of my viewport. when i give 'br' in setPosition method the panel is not visible in the viewport itself. Kindly Help

Comment: Why not adding a simple css `right:0;bottom:0;` to floating panel, instead of using setPosition ?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'br-br'. That will align the bottom right of your panel to the bottom right of the viewport. 'br' aligns the top left of you panel with the bottom right of the viewport